# Mysql password Error in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

When i try to connect a remote mysql server from my localhost i get this error:

```
Could not connect: mysqlnd cannot connect to MySQL 4.1+ using the old insecure
authentication. Please use an administration tool to reset your password with
the command SET PASSWORD = PASSWORD('your_existing_password').
This will store a new, and more
secure, hash value in mysql.user. If this user is used in other scripts executed
by PHP 5.2 or earlier you might need to remove the old-passwords flag from 
your my.cnf file
```

Any idea why it gives this error?

Comment: related question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10420831/1031312

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It gives this error because your MySQL server uses the *old* way of storing password -- and not the *new* way, which is more secure.

The mysqlnd driver, which has been introduced with PHP 5.3, doesn't support the old authentication way.

So, you have to modify your MySQL configuration, to use the new, more secure way.

The error message you get is indicating you how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

this helped me

http://www.phpro.org/articles/Database-Connection-Failed-Mysqlnd-Cannot-Connect-To-MySQL.html

### quick fix

as db user

```
SET SESSION old_passwords=0; 
SET PASSWORD=PASSWORD('my_password');
```

as admin

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

### real fix

open up your my.conf file and comment out the following line

```
old_passwords=1
```

Restart MySQL. this will ensure MySQL never uses the old passwords again.

as db user

```
SET PASSWORD=PASSWORD('my_password');
```

as admin

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be an issue when running PHP <=5.2  code in PHP 5.3+: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?52,403493,411125#msg-411125